# PostgreSQL Transaction ID went backwards

Tags: postgresql, transactions

In PostgreSQL 9.0, I have a table that keeps tracks of last processed transactions. For some reason, it went backwards (in time)! Here is the table data:

```
seq_id | tx_id
   628 | 10112
   629 | 10118
   630 | 10124
   631 | 10130
   632 | 10136
   654 | 10160
   655 | 10166  <---
   656 |  4070  <---
   657 |  4071
   658 |  4084
   659 |  4090
   660 |  4096
```

How can this happen? Can a restart of the database induce such behavior?

Thanks for any hints.

Regards,

D.

Comment: What are the column types? int/xid?

Comment: Table description:
    seq_id  bigserial NOT NULL,
    tx_id   integer   NOT NULL UNIQUE

seq_id primary key.

Comment: Where does tx_id come from? If it is a PostgreSQL transaction ID, those are based on an unsigned 32 bit number which cycles around -- these will not be unique over any extended period of time. This might be useful reading: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an invalid issue. Please ignore.

It turns out that the issue came out of restoring the table from a backup and continue working with (invalid) previous data, in a newly created database :-(

Thanks you for all those who responded already.

Case closed.

**Lesson learned**: TXID will NOT go backwards and they do get synced to a slave instance if you're using a Master/Slave setup. TXID rollovers are also correctly handled. Hope this will help others who might be thinking TXID can go backwards!